# Excel: Display collection of month names generated from start and end date?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a table to record articles published each month. However, the months I work with different clients vary based on the campaign length. For example, Client A is on a six month contract from March to September. Client B is on a 12 month contract starting from February.

Rather than creating a bespoke list of the relevant months each time, I want to automatically generate the list based on campaign start and finish.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate how this might look:

[image: example_spreadsheet]

Below is an example of expected output from the above, what I would like to achieve:

[image: expected_output]

Currently, the only month that's generated is the last one. And it goes into A6 (I would have hoped A5, but I feel like I'm trying to speak a language using Google Translate, so...).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub CreateReport()
    Dim uniqueMonths As Collection
    Set uniqueMonths = New Collection

    Dim dateRange As Range
    Set dateRange = Range("B2:C2")

On Error Resume Next

    Dim currentRange As Range
    For Each currentRange In dateRange.Cells

If currentRange.Value <> "" Then

    Dim tempDate As Date: tempDate = CDate(currentRange.Text)
    Dim parsedDateString As String: parsedDateString = Format(tempDate, "MMM")
    uniqueMonths.Add item:=parsedDateString, Key:=parsedDateString

End If

Next currentRange

On Error GoTo 0

    Dim uniqueMonth As Variant
    For Each uniqueMonth In uniqueMonths

Debug.Print uniqueMonth

Next uniqueMonth

    Dim item As Variant, currentRow As Long
    currentRow = 5
    For Each item In uniqueMonths
    dateRange.Cells(currentRow, 0).Value = item
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next item

End Sub
```

Comment: What would be the expected output? Can you edit your question and add an example of expected output?

Comment: No problem - edited and added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming A2 & B2 are already dates,

```
Sub CreateReport()
Dim mth as Date, endmth as Date, orow as Integer

mth = worksheetfunction.eomonth(activesheet.cells(2,1).value,0)
endmth = worksheetfunction.eomonth(activesheet.cells(2,2).value,0)
orow = 5
Do
    Activesheet.cells(orow,1).value = worksheetfunction.min(activesheet.cells(2,2).value,mth)
'    Activesheet.cells(orow,1).numberformat = "mmm"  'uncomment for automatic formatting 
    orow = orow + 1
    mth = worksheetfunction.eomonth(mth,1)
Loop While mth <= endmth
End Sub
```

This actually puts dates into your output column which can custom format as "mmm" if necessary.  If you decide you actually just want text in those columns then just wrap the min(endmth,mth) in a worksheetfunction.text function with a "mmm" format.

Comment: Hi Chris, this sounds great. When I run it though, it's highlighting the min function with a 'Compile error Sub or Function not defined'. I inserted worksheetfunction. in front of 'min', which prevented the error. While it returns the correct number of months, they're all the same month (whatever the earliest one is - from the min function? let me know if I've tweaked it incorrectly).

Comment: Absolutely correct, worksheetfunction.  But it should also be cells(2,2) - Fixed it in an edit.

Comment: That makes sense. Works like a dream. Many thanks!

Comment: I ended up making another tweak. The end month wasn't coming up. So I included Do Until mth = endmth and removed the While statement near the end.

Comment: Probably works.  Could also have changed While to <=.  Curious...  did you autoformat the month?     Sorry for being lazy.  Should have tested it myself

Comment: No worries. Yes, I did autoformat the month.

Answer (score 3):

**User defined function via `Evaluate`**

Simply enter `=GetCampaignMonths(A2,B2)` into cell `A5`.

*If you don't dispose of the newer dynamic versions 2019+/MS365, it's necessary to enter a `CSE` (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to finish an {array formula}:*

**Explanation**

Basically this displays all results as **dynamic (spill) range**, profiting from an evaluation of a code **one liner** ...

e.g. Jan..Dec (12 months represented by column addresses)*

```
=TEXT(DATE(0,Column(A:L),1),"mmmm")
```

If you want to include further years, the udf simply adds the years difference *(section a)* multiplied by 12 to the column numbers *(c.f. section b)*.

The evaluation of the DATE() function (c.f. section c) gets even successive years correctly, TEXT() returns the (English) months names *formatted via `"mmmm"`*.

```
Public Function GetCampaignMonths(StartDate As Date, StopDate As Date)
'Purpose: get vertical 2-dim array of month names
'a) get years difference
    Dim yrs As Long: yrs = Year(StopDate) - Year(StartDate)
'b) get column numbers representing months
    Dim cols As String
    cols = Split(Cells(, month(StartDate)).Address, "$")(1)
    cols = cols & ":" & Split(Cells(, month(StopDate) + Abs(yrs * 12)).Address, "$")(1)
'c) evaluate dates
    Dim months
    months = Evaluate("Text(Date(0,Column(" & cols & "),1),""mmmm"")")
    GetCampaignMonths = Application.Transpose(months)
End Function
```

Comment: This is pretty smart, actually, but I cannot make it work. I'm entering it as array formula in Excel 2007, but it return only March. Could be because my Excel is too old?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thx for response: Can't verify at the moment (using MS365), but would appreciate any versioning hint

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because my Excel is old, tbh. Let me test it later on MS365 tonight

Comment: I am back... I can confirm that it works on 2016 Plus. Nice code, as usually, voted up. You deserve a price for originality (tried the meta...).  looking at it, I think it will be more compact using Row evaluation. No need to transpose the array, too :) I have 10 minutes now and I will try doing it. If not successful, I will try it in the evening when I will be at home.

Comment: Posted the 'Row' evaluation version... :) Did you receive the 5 points bonus after my above comment? I tried "You deserve a price for originality"... Was it triggering some meta tags?

Comment: Strangely, somebody voted up my answer, but no any points have been counted for me... I do not care about notoriety points, but I would like to understand why. I will donate 1000 such points just to understand what is happening... To be my above intention to test the meta tag...? **Edited**: It was only delayed... It came now. You did not say anything about the potential 'bonus'...

Comment: @FaneDuru For sure, the `Row` evaluation in your *"replay"* simplifies the process,btw +) whereas *my `Column` approach followed the idea to get a "flat" array returned replacing the months arrays in several posts*. - Referring to your edit with excuses for the delay: *no, I couldn't notice such a bonus today at SO.*

Comment: So, my 5 points came from the sky, after your comment... :) Next time, I will use exactly your sentence, to see if it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make an Array with the month names and then loop trough it accordting to initial month and end month:

```
Sub test()
Dim IniDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Months As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim zz As Long

IniDate = CDate(Range("A2").Value)
EndDate = CDate(Range("b2").Value)

Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

zz = 5
For i = Month(IniDate) - 1 To Month(EndDate) - 1 Step 1
    Range("A" & zz) = Months(i)
    zz = zz + 1
Next i

Erase Months

End Sub
```

[image]

For this code to work, both dates must be recognized as dates properly. Make sure of that or it won't work.

**IMPORTANT**: This will work **only** with dates in same year, unfortunately... I noticed that right now.

**UPDATE:** You can benefit from DateAdd and DateDiff to make a code so it works even in different years :)

> [DateAdd
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function)
>
> [DateDiff
> Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function)

```
Sub test2()
Dim IniDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Months As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim zz As Long
Dim TotalMonths As Byte

IniDate = CDate(Range("A2").Value)
EndDate = CDate(Range("b2").Value)

Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

TotalMonths = DateDiff("m", IniDate, EndDate, vbMonday)


zz = 5
For i = 0 To TotalMonths Step 1
    Range("A" & zz).Value = Months(Month(DateAdd("m", i, IniDate)) - 1)
    zz = zz + 1
Next i

Erase Months


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Foxfire - works great, and I also appreciate its simplicity! I do, however, need to figure out a way of making it work across two years - as you yourself acknowledge.

Comment: @Patricia please check updated answer and look second code

Comment: A one liner to get the month names is: `[Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"mmmm")]`; see my answer using evaluation. @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with functions, no VBA required:

Office 365

```
A5: =EOMONTH(Campaign_Start,SEQUENCE(1+DATEDIF(Campaign_Start,Campaign_End,"m")+(DAY(Campaign_End)<DAY(Campaign_Start)),,0))
```

and the results will `SPILL` down as far as needed.

Format the cells as `mmm`

If you do not have Office 365, then try:

```
=EOMONTH(Campaign_Start,-1+ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,1+DATEDIF(Campaign_Start,Campaign_End,"m")+(DAY(Campaign_End)<DAY(Campaign_Start)))))
```

If your version of Excel does not have dynamic arrays where the results `SPILL`, you will need to enter the formula in the individual cells as an array, and it would require further modification.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for DATEDIF() which was a new one on me ... oddly that does not appear in suggestions as I type =DATE... directly into a cell, or indeed in the Formula Manager (in the Date & Time category). But the formula still works.

Comment: @DS_London It's actually been around for many versions, but usually doesn't appear in the Formula Manager.  See [DateDif Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) for HELP.

Comment: I like the 'we've provided this function, but it doesn't work well' caveat in the MS Help! I guess that is why they have left it out of the Formula Manager.

Comment: It has been a bit flakey over the various iterations, but performance with the "m" parameter has been stable.

Answer (score 1):

As replay to @T.M. nice piece of code. The version using `Row` Evaluation:

```
Function GetCampaignMnths(StartDate As Date, StopDate As Date)
'Purpose: get vertical 2-dim array of month names
'b) get rows numbers representing months
    Dim monthsNo As Long, rows As String
    monthsNo = DateDiff("m", StartDate, StopDate, vbMonday)
    rows = Month(StartDate) & ":" & monthsNo + Month(StartDate)
'c) evaluate dates
    Dim months
    months = Evaluate("Text(Date(0,row(" & rows & "),1),""mmmm"")")
    GetCampaignMnths = months
End Function
```

It can be easily tested using the next sub:

```
Sub testGetCampaignMohths()
   Dim arr
   arr = GetCampaignMnths("01.03.2021", "01.08.2022") 'use here date recognized by yor localization. Or build them using DateSerial
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arr), "|")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub GenerateMonthsL()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, firstM As Long, lastM As Long, arrD, arrProj, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet

   firstM = month(sh.Range("A2").Value2)
   lastM = month(sh.Range("B2").Value2)
   arrD = Split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Dec", ",")
   ReDim arrProj(lastM - firstM + 1)
   For i = firstM - 1 To lastM - 1
        arrProj(k) = arrD(i): k = k + 1
   Next
   ReDim Preserve arrProj(k - 1)
   sh.Range("A5").Resize(UBound(arrProj) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrProj)
   With sh.Range("A4:B4")
        .value = Array("Months", "Articles Published")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Color = 14998742
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Imo this post doesn't allow calculation of successive years; see my short cut to evaluate dates.

Comment: @T.M. Of course, not... It has not been required in the question. When I came back now, I could see a comment specifying it, after the first answer has been posted.

Comment: @T.M. Very busy now, but I will come back here when I will have some time...

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather avoid VBA entirely, Excel's array functions let you do this using spreadsheet formulae (if your version of Excel is recent enough).

Put this formula in Cell A5 (assuming start date in A2, and end date in B2):

```
=LET(mnths,1+(12*YEAR(B2)+MONTH(B2)-(12*YEAR(A2)+MONTH(A2))),s,SEQUENCE(mnths),TEXT(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+(s-1),1),"mmm"))
```

If you have more than a year, you can amend the TEXT format string to "mmm-yy".

[image]

Comment: Sadly my version of Excel isn't recent enough. Thanks for sharing a non-VBA option, though. Interesting to see other approaches. I'm not particularly well-versed in VBA, but I'm finding it a great option when designing spreadsheets for my colleagues' use - less room for accidentally deleting formulae!